# StaticResource found when added during runtime, but not on launch

Tags: wpf

I have this parent control that displays its `CurrentViewModel`, and instance of `ViewModelWithExam`, using the data templates provided.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Gui.Views.ExamsTabView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Gui.Views.Tabs.ExamsTabViews"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Gui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:DataManagement;assembly=DataManagement"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ExamInfoViewModel}">
            <views:ExamInfoView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ExamAcquireImageViewModel}">
            <views:ExamAcquireImageView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ExamEditImageViewModel}">
            <views:ExamEditImageView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!--Reuseable control to display the simple exam header-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExamHeader" DataType="{x:Type data:Exam}">
            <views:ExamHeaderView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any of the views can use the `ExamHeader` to display their `Exam` property:

```xml
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ExamHeader}" Content="{Binding Exam}"/>
```

The `ExamHeader` template, however, exhibits odd behavior. If I remove the `x:Key` property from the template, and remove the `ContentTemplate` property from the `ContentControl`, *and then launch the app*, the header displays, as expected.

*While the app is running*, if I add back the `x:Key`, the header disappears and is replaced by the classname of the Exam. As expected. If I then add back the `ContentTemplate` to point to the header template, the header template shows. It works.

However, if I *launch* the app with the `x:Key` and `ContentTemplate` in place, then loading a page with a header puts the application in break mode, saying "The resource 'ExamHeader' could not be found." Indeed, when the app isn't running, this error appears under the `ControlTemplate` property.

But, to say again, if I add in the `x:Key` and `ContentTemplate` *while the app is running*, it work fine!

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a resource ordering issue. Try moving the `ExamHeader` resource to the top of your resources:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <!--Reuseable control to display the simple exam header-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExamHeader" DataType="{x:Type data:Exam}">
            <views:ExamHeaderView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ExamInfoViewModel}">
            <views:ExamInfoView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ExamAcquireImageViewModel}">
            <views:ExamAcquireImageView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ExamEditImageViewModel}">
            <views:ExamEditImageView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. However, it doesn't work. Thanks though!

Comment: As a test, does it work if you put the ExamHeader resource into Application resources?

Comment: Can't add it directly to `<Appication.Resources>` (must be a `ResourceDictionary` so I added it to a resource dictionary and that does work.